# Executing who -m from ant

Tags: ant, exec

I am trying to execute the **"who -m"** command from Apache ant without success.

Here is my ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="default" default="who.am.i">
    <target name="who.am.i">
        <exec executable="who" outputproperty="myOutput">
            <arg value="-m"/>
        </exec>
        <echo message="I am = ${myOutput}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The result is blank.

```
[echo] I am =
```

If I run exec without the argument, it displays the correct result:

```
        <exec executable="who" outputproperty="myOutput">
        </exec>

[echo] host.name = gary     tty8         2014-02-03 12:04 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/0        2014-02-03 12:09 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/1        2014-02-03 12:23 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/2        2014-02-04 11:36 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/4        2014-02-05 13:27 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/7        2014-02-04 12:23 (:0)
[echo] gary     pts/8        2014-02-06 12:44 (:0)
```

If I run the who -m command from a terminal it displays what I am looking for:

```
who -m
gary     pts/8        2014-02-06 12:44 (:0)
```

Any ideas why ant is not accepting the -m argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I decided to go another route.

In **~/.bashrc** I added the following line:

```
who -m | awk '{print $5}' > ~/.whoami.out
```

And to make it global I just added it to **/etc/bashrc**

This will write to the ~/.whoami.out file every time I log into the remote system.

In my ant script I read the content of this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="default" default="default">

    <target name="test.who.key">
        <loadfile property="who.key" srcFile="${user.home}/.whoami.out" failonerror="false"/>
        <condition property="who.cond">
            <isset property="who.key"/>
        </condition>
        <condition property="who.cond2">
            <not>
                <isset property="who.key"/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="init.who.key" depends="test.who.key" if="who.cond">
        <echo message="WHO EXIST"/>
        <property name="whoAmI" value="${who.key}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init.not.who.key" depends="test.who.key" if="who.cond2">
        <echo message="WHO DOES NOT EXIST"/>
        <property name="whoAmI" value=""/>
    </target>    

    <target name="default" depends="init.who.key, init.not.who.key">
        <echo message="whoAmI = ${whoAmI}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try executing as shell executable to see it that helps. It helps to invoke shell with exact unix command you want to run.

```
<exec executable="sh" outputproperty="myOutput">
   <arg value="who -m"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Tried it with no success, decided to go the bashrc route

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which flavour of Unix you have, but on Solaris I get this error message when I try your task:

```
[echo] $ Must be attached to terminal for 'am I' option
```

In contrast, on OSX it *appears* to work, but says:

```
[echo] I am = mjc      tty??    Feb  7 02:35
```

note the `??` - it's also not finding the terminal for the session.

I suspect that in your case it is silently failing for the same reason as the Solaris test  - namely that the shell forked by Ant (i.e. by java) isn't associated with your terminal session.

(There may well be a workaround, but I'm not aware of it, and if there is one, it is unlikely to be portable.)

Comment: I was testing it om my Linux box. Whe I run it on Solaris I also get: Must be attached to terminal for 'am I' option.